# undefined method `name' for "Ascii85":String in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having the existing source code in rails 2.3.2, while running rake gems:install it shows the error like "undefined method `name' for "Ascii85":String".

I think it is the problem due to rubygems version. I am using ruby 1.8.7, rails 2.3.2, gem 1.3.7.

#### Update:

Now I solved the above problem by running `sudo rake gems:install` but now my problem is while running the rake `db:migtare`

```
Missing these required gems:
  activemerchant  = 1.4.1



   You're running:
      ruby 1.8.7.299 at /usr/bin/ruby1.8
      rubygems 1.3.6 at /home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302, /home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@global
    
    Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.
```

But i have already installed the activemerchant gem, here is the gem list

```
fstech@Blrfstech12:~/workspace/ff$ sudo gem list activemerchant

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

activemerchant (1.15.0, 1.4.1)
fstech@Blrfstech12:~/workspace/ff$
```

> rake gems:install --trace

```
fstech@Blrfstech12:~/workspace/ff$ rake gems:install --trace
rake/rdoctask is deprecated.  Use rdoc/task instead (in RDoc 2.4.2+)
** Invoke gems:install (first_time)
** Invoke gems:base (first_time)
** Execute gems:base
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
RubyGem version error: activesupport(2.2.2 not = 3.0.9)
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:777:in `report_activate_error'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:211:in `activate'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:246:in `activate'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `activate'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/acts_as_ferret-0.5.2/lib/acts_as_ferret/railtie.rb:2
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/acts_as_ferret-0.5.2/lib/acts_as_ferret.rb:92
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:179:in `load'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:305:in `load_gems'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:305:in `each'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:305:in `load_gems'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:167:in `process'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/home/fstech/workspace/ff/config/environment.rb:22
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/tasks/gems.rake:17
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `invoke_task'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `top_level'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `each'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `top_level'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `top_level'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in `run'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/bin/rake:19
no such file to load -- faraday
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/faraday_middleware-0.6.5/lib/faraday_middleware.rb:1
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/twitter-1.6.0/lib/twitter/connection.rb:1
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/twitter-1.6.0/lib/twitter/api.rb:3
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/twitter-1.6.0/lib/twitter.rb:1
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:179:in `load'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:305:in `load_gems'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:305:in `each'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:305:in `load_gems'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:167:in `process'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/home/fstech/workspace/ff/config/environment.rb:22
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/tasks/gems.rake:17
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `invoke_task'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `top_level'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `each'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `top_level'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `top_level'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in `run'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/fstech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/bin/rake:19
** Execute gems:install
gem install activemerchant --version "= 1.4.1"
Successfully installed activemerchant-1.4.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for activemerchant-1.4.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for activemerchant-1.4.1...
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Please provide the actual stack trace returned by `rake gems:install --trace` as well as the output of `gem list`.

Comment: You should rather update your question, and not add an answer which is not an answer. Also, did you mean you run rake db:migrate? And what is that missing file "faraday"?

Comment: How does your config/environment.rb look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't feel competent enough to help you directly with these gems, but I suspect that you have run (and will run) into problems because of various versions of installed gems. I know that gems were designed to help in that, but...

You may want to try to use bundler to help you manage the versions of gems. See an article http://blog.tag.ca/using-bundler-with-rails-2 . I haven't tested it myself (because I have skipped from Rails 1 directly to Rails 3), but it may save you a lot of troubles.